# How to hide and show an object on scene in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, show-hide, scene

I have an object which is composed of spheres on my scene. And I have a hide and show button.
The flow of my program is like that. For example, when I select one of the spheres (I used raycasting for select a sphere) then **click the hide button, this sphere will be hidden.** And after then click the show button it will be shown. But I don't know how can I do it.
I used three.js for creating my scene.
And I don't find any example for my question. How can I do it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Each `Object3D` has a `.visible` attribute. From (r84) https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=object3#Reference/Core/Object3D

Comment: Actually, I want to an example. Because I can't imagine.

Comment: @ŞeymaYaman What kind of example do you want? How to set a property to `true` or `false`?

Comment: Little jsfiddle example. I try to write but I get an error.

Comment: That's why it's better to show what you've tried already (jsfiddle, codepen etc)

Comment: https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-09/02-selecting-objects.html  I wrote my code according to this example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

simply use the object traverse method to hide the mesh in three.js.
In my code hide the object based on its name

```
object.traverse ( function (child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        child.visible = true;
    }
});
```

Here is the working sample for Object show/hide option
http://jsfiddle.net/ddbTy/287/

I think it should be helpful,..

Comment: Thank you. It is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
object.visible = false; //Invisible
object.visible = true;  //Visible
```