# What Autodesk Forge event to listen to to know when can call viewer.hideAll and viewer.show methods

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I call `viewer.hideAll` and then `viewer.show` to implement custom filtering functionality in Forge Viewer. If I have a list of dbids for certain elements and I call two methods mentioned above as soon as viewer gets initialized, then nothing happens. I mean no elements get hidden or shown and no error gets thrown from the Forge viewer instance.

Based on information that I have right now, I can subscribe to `Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT` event to know when to call above methods, but it takes at least 20 seconds (for 200mb model) and sometimes even takes 60 seconds (for 1gb model) to fire that event. Is there some other event that fires earlier than `Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT` that I can use to know when to call `viewer.hideAll` and `viewer.show` methods?

Also, if someone knows and shares a better way to implement filtering functionality in the Forge viewer, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Both `viewer.hideAll` and `viewer.show` methods control the node visibilities, so you must wait for the geometries to be loaded (i.e. when `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` gets fired. )

```js
viewer.addEventListener(
    Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
    (event) => {
       // viewer.hideAll
       // viewer.show
    });
```

Comment: I just checked `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` and it fires once all the geometries loaded completely which takes forever. Even `Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT` fires before that and I currently use it to know when to call `viewer.hideAll` and `viewer.show`.
It doesn't make sense for Forge to wait till all the meshes are loaded to enabled these methods. You don't need meshes to know if the object is hidden, you only need to know if the object is present, but for that you don't need material and geometry info.

Comment: Visibility control is to set visible flags on fragments (meshes, geometries). InstanceTree is just the hierarchy of the model, not geometries. It's based on the three.js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609602/how-to-hide-and-show-an-object-on-scene-in-three-js